# Same tab space on Sublime/Notepad++

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++

Imagine this sentence:

```
I---like-java.
```

I want to ident this setence using sublime or notepad++ to:

```
I-like-java.
```

Edit:

`-` stands for an empty space

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++, you can do:

Find what: `-{2,}`
Replace with: `-`

This will replace two or more dash with only one.

**Update after question edit:**

In order to remove multiple spaces, just do the same as above by exchanging dash with space:

Find what: `\h{2,}`
Replace with: `Just one space`

Where `\h` means any horizontal space.

Comment: The `\s` also matches the new line characters `\r` and `\n`, so the `\s{2,}` above will also join lines together (with Windows line endings). It may be safer to use `-{2,}` where `-` means space.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: True, corrected.

Comment: @downvoter: May have I an explanation?

Comment: Not me. I thought it a good answer to a poor question.